# ExtJs Existing record deleted when adding a new record

Tags: javascript, extjs

Scenario is simple.

I have one store, which gets populated from an API end point. 
For this example, we are going to assume we have one record in that store. 
Important detail on this is that the internal id of our record is 2.

Now, we create a new model instance and populate it with some data. Add to the store. This record has an id of 1. Store.add(new model instance) works fine.

Now, when we make a third record, and attempt to add it to the store, we run into an issue. The id of the third record is 2. The id of the first record that we have in the store is 2.

The third record overrides the first record, sending out a delete for the record that was obtained from the endpoint.

Is this a bug, or a feature...

Answer (score 1):

Its a feature, store model `idProperty` used as unique identifier for record and by default its `'id'`, so when you trying to add new record and record with the same `'id'` already exists in the store you actually update existing record.

You have to change your store model [`idProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty).

Comment: Thanks. However, i do have an idProperty set in the model to the primary key for this entity. When a new instance of the model is created, the id is generated clientside. After save, the record gets reloaded with the actual id of the entity from the DB.

Comment: setting the id to something else does indeed fix the issue,

Comment: Maybe you have to generate (pseudo)random value for `'id'` property before you load actual data from remote source?